# Rails admin show username instead of User #5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

How to configure rails admin to show **username** instead of **User #user_id** in different model?

Now I have this:

```
config.model "Post" do
    edit do
      field :title
      field :body
      field :created_at

    end
  end
```

And I want to have something like this:

```
config.model "Post" do
    edit do
      .....

      field self.username
    end
  end
```

Here's what I have when editing post to let you know what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work in list views when in tabular format.  See the rails admin [docs](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Railsadmin-DSL) for additional detail.

```
config.model "Post" do
  list do
    field :title
    field :body
    field :created_at
    field :user do
      pretty_value do
        value.username
      end
    end
  end
  edit do
    field :user_id do
      formatted_value do
        value.try(:user).try(:username)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit**

This should cover edits too.

Comment: Does your user model have a username column?

Comment: I've made modifications. Try again.